# ros run couldn't find executable file after catkin build and source

Tags: executable, ros, catkin

I'm trying to run an executable, but I'm getting the following error, I ran

```
catkin build
```

and then

```
source ~/emvs_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

after this running the following command shows this message

```
rosrun mapper_emvs run_emvs
```

the error is

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run_emvs below /home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src/rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs
```

this is the cmake file:

```
project(mapper_emvs)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo) # Release, RelWithDebInfo
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -fopenmp -std=c++11 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set(HEADERS
  include/mapper_emvs/mapper_emvs.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/data_loading.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/depth_vector.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/trajectory.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/geometry_utils.hpp
  include/mapper_emvs/median_filtering.hpp
)

set(SOURCES
  src/mapper_emvs.cpp
  src/data_loading.cpp
  src/median_filtering.cpp
)

option(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH "Use linear spacing in inverse depth (if OFF, will use linear spacing in depth)" ON)
if(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
    add_definitions(-DUSE_INVERSE_DEPTH)
endif(DEFINE_USE_INVERSE_DEPTH)

cs_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

# Executables
################################################################################

cs_add_executable(run_emvs src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(run_emvs ${PROJECT_NAME})

################################################################################
cs_install()
cs_export()
```

Comment: I don't really understand why rosrun is looking for executable under `/src/rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs`, because it shouldn't be there. Could you try to test and use catkin_make instead?

Comment: It worked using catkin_make :D :D.Even though I didn't understand why it didn't work by catkin build !

Comment: @VictoriaKepler Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm having this error, do you have an idea what might be the cause ? [fatal error: pcl/registration/incremental_registration.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.] @VictoriaKepler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that experienced with `catkin build`, but I'm glad that `catkim_make` fixed your problem.

Answering your second question, it means that this header file `incremental_registration.h` is not on the place your program is looking for it. However, I suggest you to close this question and create another one since they are not related.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by adding the following line to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
catkin_package()
```